# mapping a composite key with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to map one to many relationship using Hibernate :

I have a profil with multiple properties:

**Profil.java**

```
 public class Profil {

 private String idProfil;

 private String name; 


 private Set<Properties> setProperties;

 }
```

**Properties.java**

```
  public class Properties {

 private CompositeId id;

 private String  length;

 private String  heigth;

 private String  width;

}
```

and a **compositeId.java**

```
public class CompositeId {

private String idPropertiy; 

private String idProfil;//idProfil is a foreign key 
}
```

idProperty is assigned manually.

idProfil is assigned automatically.

can anyone help  me to write the hbm.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate Synchronizer Eclipse plugin to generate the *.hbm files and its associated java classes.

[HibernateSynchronizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernatesynch/)